# angular-translate Flash of IDs

Tags: angularjs, internationalization

I'm currently developping a web app with AngularJS and Angular-translate.

While my page is loading, the translation keys are displayed for a very short while. As I don't want it, i'm looking for a solution.

Here is my app's config:

```
.config(['$translateProvider', function($translateProvider) {
        $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
            prefix: '/front/translations/',
            suffix: '/'
        });
        $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('En');
        $translateProvider.useLocalStorage();
    }])
```

Can anyone tell me what I made wrong?

Answer (score 0):

angular-translate comes with a `translate-cloak` directive. You can read about it here http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/12_asynchronous-loading#asynchronous-loading_fouc---flash-of-untranslated-content

hope this helps :)

Comment: current version doesnot requried ng-cloak